# how to stop a button from being pressed twice

Tags: javascript

SO i'm making a god where if you click enter, it fires a cannonball, and the enter button will add speed to the ball. the problem is that when i click enter multiple times, I don't know how to make it so that people can't click it multiple times to make the cannon super fast. also I don't know how to click the button enter, so i just used arrow up.

```
document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.repeat) return; // Do nothing

  const { key } = e;

  switch(key) {
    case 'ArrowUp':
      cannonball.dx++,
      cannonball.dy++
      break;
  }
};
```

here is the thing I'm using it in

```
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
//variables
const cannon = {
w: 150,
h: 75,
x:0,
y:0
}

const cannonball = {
x: 77,
y: 565,
r:25,
dx:0,
dy:0
}

const cannonRotate = {
degree: -43.5
}



//running the whole function
function animate(){
c.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);
//cannon
c.save();
c.translate(-25,600);
c.rotate(cannonRotate.degree * Math.PI / 180);
c.fillStyle = '#000';
c.fillRect(cannon.x,cannon.y,cannon.w,cannon.h);
c.restore();

//cannonball
c.beginPath();
c.arc(cannonball.x,cannonball.y, cannonball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
c.fillStyle = '#000';
c.fill();

cannonball.x += cannonball.dx;
cannonball.y -= cannonball.dy;



document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.repeat) return; // Do nothing

  const { key } = e;

  switch(key) {
    case 'ArrowUp':
      cannonball.dx += 5,
      cannonball.dy += 5
      break;
  }
};

requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question, you want to limit the interval between key presses, correct? So you can do it by implementing an timer that ignores next key presses until it finishes:

```
let ignoreKeyPress = false;

document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.repeat || ignoreKeyPress) return; // Do nothing

  ignoreKeyPress = true;
  setTimeout(() => ignoreKeyPress = false, 1000); // change the 1000 to the interval between keypresses that you want in miliseconds.

  const { key } = e;

  switch(key) {
    case 'ArrowUp':
      cannonball.dx++,
      cannonball.dy++
      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of doing this, but here's an example of throttling you can try applying to your code. The idea is to wrap a function with a closure that contains the time of the last call. For repeated calls, the last time is checked before re-calling the function. A `cooldown` variable determines how long the delay is before a re-trigger is allowed (in milliseconds). This is a general function you can apply to pretty much anything (HTTP requests, for example, to enforce rate limiting).

Beyond that, it's likely a mistake to be re-registering event handlers inside the animation loop. This should be a one-shot setup task, not something you want to do 30-60 times a second.

As for the thing you're throttling, it's unusual that the cannonball will only move when the arrow key is pressed. For the below minimal example, I'm throttling the firing rate, which (probably?) makes more sense for a game.

```js
const throttle = (fn, cooldown=1000) => {
  let lastCall = 0;
  return (...args) => {
    if (Date.now() - lastCall > cooldown) {
      lastCall = Date.now();
      fn(...args);
    }
  };
};

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";

const cannonBalls = [];

(function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (const e of cannonBalls) {
    e.dx *= 0.99;
    e.dy += 0.1;
    e.x += e.dx;
    e.y += e.dy;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(e.x, e.y, e.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
})();

const fire = throttle(() => cannonBalls.push({
  x: 10, 
  y: 10,
  dx: 10,
  dy: 0,
  r: 10
}));

document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
    !e.repeat && fire();
  }
});
```

```html
<p>press spacebar to fire</p>
```

Comment: No problem. If this went a bit above your head, just wrap any function you want to throttle with `throttle()` and optionally change the delay using the second parameter, e.g. `throttle(moveStuff, 2000)` for a 2-second delay, and you're good to go.